# Will Adblocker remove my font awesome "YouTube" icon?

Tags: css, fonts, font-awesome, font-awesome-4

I'm using [Font Awesome](http://fontawesome.io) and at the bottom of their [Icons Page](http://fontawesome.io/icons) there is a yellow(ish) warning box:

[image]

In the warning box it says:

> **Apparently**, Adblock Plus can remove Font Awesome brand icons with their *"Remove Social Media Buttons"* setting.

And I'm using the `fa-youtube-play` icon on a button, so does this mean that AdBlocker will remove my icons?

**NOTE**: No I'm not hosting any advertisements on my site.
**NOTE**: The button it redirects you to the specified YouTube video.
**NOTE**: There are no popups just a redirect.

Comment: It reads to me like it'll remove that icon if you're using the default Font Awesome icon names.

Comment: Some ad blockers have these rules for blocking sharing options (buttons, images etc). As the warning itself says: you will have to rename the icon class or disable this rule. Check this http://blog.cuberoot.in/fontawesome-hidden-facebook-and-other-social-icons/ and this https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/1799

Comment: Thanks for the information, appreciate it.

Comment: You could install Adblock Plus and try it out.....

Comment: @sorayadragon I tried it already :D It doesn't remove it but still I'm sceptical.